# Task.WhenAll creates duplicates for Task<ConcurrentDictionary>

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, interactive-brokers, tws

Class that creates list of tasks, each task returns ConcurrentDictionary

```
public List<Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>>> GetDictionaries()
{
  var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
  var tasks = new List<Task<ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>>>();

  for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++)
  {
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var done = false;
      var data = new Object();
      var eventCallback = (int id) => { data.id = id; done = true; };

      Client.asyncEvent += eventCallback;
      Client.initiateAsyncEvent(k);
      while (done == false);
      Client.asyncEvent -= eventCallback;

      results[k] = data; 
      return results;
    }));
  }

  return tasks;
}
```

Call event (task) 10 times, wait for a callback for this event, add result to the dictionary "results".

We execute 10 events (tasks), so should get 10 items in a dictionary, but when I merge dictionaries from all tasks with When.All, list contains 100 items instead of 10.

```
var tasks = GetDictionaries();

var plainListOfResults = Task
  .WhenAll(tasks)
  .Result
  .SelectMany(o => o.Keys)
  .ToList();

// Expected: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
// Actual: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ... 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

**Questions**

1. Why 10 tasks created 10 times more results then they should?
2. Why, when I replace ConcurrentDictionary with Dictionary, this code works as expected?

Comment: This is a large lump of code and most of it unrelated to the question, could you perhaps create the most minimal example of what you are trying to explain? because its not obvious

Comment: @TheGeneral tried to simplify code and rephrase the question.

Comment: Intuitively, I think that there is a difference between Dictionary and ConcurrentDictionary in how they merge items with the same key. It looks like ConcurrentDictionary creates instance of the same dictionary for each thread and when I merge thread results in When.All it thinks that all objects are unique, even with the same key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `Task` is returning the entire `ConcurrentDictionary` so when you get the set of results from `Task.WhenAll`, it contains the same dictionary 10 times.

Some additional notes:

`while (done == false);` is awful. It's probably pegging your CPU at 100% while it waits. If you're converting event based async to task based async, convert your events to tasks, or use `TaskCompletionSource`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types

If you can refactor so that the async methods just return values, like `ValueTuple`s, `Tuple`s, `KeyValuePair`s, anonymous types or your own types, and don't modify the dictionary while they run, you can also ditch the `ConcurrentDictionary` and just create the dictionary from the set of results with `ToDictionary` after the `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Actually, I'm using TaskCompletionSource, but TheGeneral asked me to simplify code, so I replaced some C# and IB stuff with the most simple pseudo-code, just to explain an idea. You can check the first version of my post by clicking "Edited X hours ago" below it :)

Comment: I am afraid, I can't return a single value from this method, it depends on API that is executing for approximately a minute and returns values to eventCallback, so the method should gather all values from API and return them as kind of Enumerable. It works fine with List and Dictionary, but creates duplicates with ConcurrentDictonary

Comment: I will try to check what async patterns I can use here, if I won't find anything appropriate, I'll use a single callback for multiple events created in a loop without Tasks, so all values will be accumulated in a ConcurrentDictionary in a single thread.